# Is there any way to limit acess to specific folders for user with impersonation permissions in exchange?

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Is there any way to limit acess to specific folders for user with impersonation permissions in exchange?

We need our service to be able to catch calendar change events. But we don't want to let it read anybody's mails and so on. Please advise!

Answer (score 0):

If you setup their permissions correctly, they should only be able to see the public folders they have rights to.  They will only be able to read emails (Inbox, I assume - or for any default folder) for other users if a user has granted them delegate permissions.  You need to grant a user Full Mailbox access to other mailboxes in order to read everything.

Comment: If I understand impersonation correctly, it allows to do everything, the user you're impersonating can. The only limitation I've foun to set up, is limitation of users, I can impersonate.

Comment: Do you mean you are logging the user into Windows using impersonation with System.Security? If so, where is your code being run? Is there a Mail profile setup for that user on the PC running the code?  If not, you'd have to use MAPI or Redemption to logon with a dynamic profile to a specific Mailbox.